# Porque al subir mi proyecto de Laravel 5.1 me da el siguiente error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>   View [welcome] not found.
>
> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
>   file_put_contents(C:\Users\Gerson Samayoa\Documents\colegiola\storage\framework/sessions/2e81d22b2a778c265898e0e7ea85b7828c2a19d2): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Ya cambié las dos líneas de código en el archivo index.php de mi carpeta public

Comment: Ya ejecutaste el comando: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Es un servidor con Cpanel no se donde puedo ejecutar eso

Comment: Deberás contactar a tu host para que te diga como acceder al shell. Una vez que puedas entrar ahí, deberás instalar composer y ejecutar el comando anterior. Eso actualizará las clases y demás archivos de tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente sea el las sesiones cache, prueba antes de subirlo realizar los siguientes comandos en tu terminal antes de subirlo, aunque no uso windows me imagino que se usa la console:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Gracias J. Rivera  te comento que si me funciono pero lo extraño es que yo hice:  php artisan config:clear y luego php artisan cache:clear no utilice el php artisan config:cache, para que sirve ese ultimo?

Comment: Saludos, realmente si solo utilizas el config:cache te funciona todo, porque ese comando hace las dos cosas de una vez, es decir, reconfigura y limpia la cache. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Borra el contenido de las carpetas donde se almacenan archivos temporales:

```
storage/framework/cache
storage/framework/session
storage/framework/views
```

En caso que no funcione, agrega a tu pregunta el contenido del controlador que llama la vista `welcome`.